# Is it possible to hard fork a private network to Constantinople?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, hardforks, clique

I have a `Proof-of-Authority` private Ethereum network that has `Byzantium EVM` version and created by `clique` engine. I have a single miner that has Geth version: `v1.8.27`.

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 23422,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "clique": {
      "period": 15,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
}
```

Please see my configuration file: [custom.json](https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/d0273ff4eedb4cdd04d78455878b80a6).

When I start geth I get following output:

```
INFO [07-10|13:46:36.647] Initialised chain configuration          
config="{ChainID: 23422 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2
EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople: <nil>  
Petersburg: <nil> Engine: clique}"
```

I assume since `Constantinople: <nil>` in the configuration file and I cannot alter the custom configuration file there is no way I can hard fork the private chain.

---

[Here:](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/44352/4575)

> The configuration is fixed via constants in the code (see
>   ChainConfig). A custom configuration can be provided in genesis
>   specification file, however, this is only applicable when setting up a
>   new chain.
>
> Hence, currently the only way to make a hard fork in a private network
>   is to ensure that all participants shutdown/upgrade/restart in a
>   predefined time slot.

// I have updated the geth version but in general I am not sure to check that whether the private chain is updated.

**[Q]** I was wondering, is it possible to hard fork a private chain that has different EVM version to `Constantinople EVM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, we need to do the same things as ethereum do for their networks on your chain.

We have two options:

**1. First is do like this answer**

[How to setup constantinople fork for private ethereum chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67794/how-to-setup-constantinople-fork-for-private-ethereum-chain/68918#68918)

**2. Modify config in the source code as below step**

Update the config as relevant with your config.json file in below file

Update `config.go` in
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/49a7ee460e839499ef41f5110b219ec8c8edc5e8/params/config.go#L66

In your case, the `config.go` should be like below

```
    // MainnetChainConfig is the chain parameters to run a node on the main network.
    MainnetChainConfig = &ChainConfig{
        ChainID:             big.NewInt(23422),
        HomesteadBlock:      big.NewInt(1),
        DAOForkBlock:        nil,
        DAOForkSupport:      true,
        EIP150Block:         big.NewInt(2),
        EIP150Hash:          common.HexToHash("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"),
        EIP155Block:         big.NewInt(3),
        EIP158Block:         big.NewInt(3),
        ByzantiumBlock:      big.NewInt(4),
        ConstantinopleBlock: big.NewInt(xxxxxx),
        PetersburgBlock:     big.NewInt(xxxxxx),
        Clique: &CliqueConfig{
            Period: 15,
            Epoch:  30000,
        },
    }
```

`xxxxxx` is the future block number you want to do hardfork on your private chain.

Furthermore, `PetersburgBlock` is the **Constantinople Fix** due to a security hole of `Constantinople` found by **chainsecurity** details on below link

https://medium.com/chainsecurity/constantinople-enables-new-reentrancy-attack-ace4088297d9

> The upcoming Constantinople Upgrade for the ethereum network
>   introduces cheaper gas cost for certain SSTORE operations. As an
>   unwanted side effect, this enables reentrancy attacks when using
>   address.transfer(...) or address.send(...) in Solidity smart
>   contracts. Previously these functions were considered reentrancy-safe,
>   which they aren’t any longer.

Then for the chain that still not enable `Constantinople`, the `ConstantinopleBlock` and `PetersburgBlock` will be the same block number.

And we need to create the genesis allocation constants in genesis_alloc.go also by running `mkalloc` like in the guide in below guidance.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/6bd896a97f0c86fdb6d0538f5f839d7ea104e888/core/mkalloc.go#L24

Then modify the default genesis block on this below line also

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/6bd896a97f0c86fdb6d0538f5f839d7ea104e888/core/genesis.go#L317

you can do sanity check by looking into the output log; `Constantinople` and `Petersburg` must display the block number that we set on the `config.go`

```
INFO [07-10|13:46:36.647] Initialised chain configuration          
config="{ChainID: 23422 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2
EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople: <xxxxxx>  
Petersburg: <xxxxxx> Engine: clique}"
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Should I add `ConstantinopleBlock: big.NewInt(<blockNumber>)` into my `custom.json` file and re-run the signer nodes? But the configuration is fixed I cannot update it @Ha ĐANG

Comment: Seems not, we can only use config file once time when running geth init

Comment: the config in source code will overwrite the existing config then we dont need worry about that; even ethereum mainnet also need to do the same way

Comment: Should only the signer nodes make this change on the `go-ethereum/params/config.go` file? or all the connected nodes to the private-network as well? @Ha ĐANG

Comment: I think all due to they introduced some new opcode also

Comment: Got it, since all nodes are required the make that change, when all nodes download go-ethereum than all should make the update on the following `go-ethereum/params/config.go` otherwise, they won't be sync with the hard-forked chain, right?. @Ha ĐANG

Comment: Totally right! By the way, the config was fixed  when the hard fork number was decided. Then client only need to get the latest source code to run other than update the code by themselves

Comment: After making the changes that you have recommended, is there any way to verify/check that the private-network is hard-forked? @Ha ĐANG

Comment: Basically, if node can sign/sync beyond the harkfork block number that mean the harkfork was successfully

Comment: Based on your answer I shoul update `TestnetChainConfig` and `MainnetChainConfig`, right? or if I only update `TestnetChainConfig` would it be enough? `TestnetChainConfig contains the chain parameters to run a node on the Ropsten test network.`@Ha ĐANG

Comment: There is no option for the `private-network` on the `config.go` I have tried both but it did not work. @Ha ĐANG

Comment: You should make it for your private chain; modify the code for your chain, don’t need to keep the value of the existing value for etheruem mainnet and testnet

Comment: Move the value of your chain in json file you posted to the config.go

Comment: You should modify the mainnet only; but due to you use the poa then it similar to’ rinkeby

Comment: I updated the answer to put `config.go` of your chain, please take a look

Comment: I made the updated you recommended but still when I re-run the `geth` I get the `Constantinople: <nil>` output. I thin MainnetChain does not refer to the private network @Ha ĐANG

Comment: your private chain can be the mainnet, no problem! it seems that you need to add  genesis data into the source code also.

Comment: by the way, can you try to update the json file and call `geth init`. Some one say that we can update config by that way

Comment: refer to this https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/6bd896a97f0c86fdb6d0538f5f839d7ea104e888/core/mkalloc.go#L24 to make your `genesis.json` data into source code

Comment: I have kept the `config.go` file as it is update the genesis.json file via adding `    "constantinopleBlock": 2862930, "petersburgBlock": 2862930,`, remove the chain and started with `geth init` now I can see `Constantinople: 2862930  ConstantinopleFix: 2862930` as output of the `geth`, I will do this for all the nodes in the network

Comment: if you remove chain then how can you reserve your chain data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96202/discussion-between-alper-and-ha-dang).

Comment: Should I apply similiar approach to fork for Istanbul as well? @Ha ĐANG

Comment: Yes, we can do the same thing for Istanbul