# Is it possible to hard fork a private network to Berlin?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, hardforks, clique

I have a `Proof-of-Authority` private Ethereum network that has `Istanbul EVM` version and created by `clique` engine. I have multiple signer nodes that has Geth version: `v1.10.1-stable-c2d2f4ed`.

```
"config": {
    "chainId": 23422,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "constantinopleBlock": 2862930,
    "petersburgBlock": 2862930,
    "istanbulBlock": 3831182,
    "clique": {
      "period": 15,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
```

Please see my configuration file: [custom.json](https://github.com/avatar-lavventura/eBlocPOA/blob/master/custom.json).

When I start `geth` I get following output:

`"{ChainID: 23422 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople: 2862930 Petersburg: 2862930 Istanbul: 3831182, Muir Glacier: <nil>, Berlin: <nil>, YOLO v3: <nil>, Engine: clique}"`

**[Q]** I was wondering, is it possible to hard fork a private chain that has different EVM version to [`Berlin EVM`](https://beincrypto.com/ethereum-activates-berlin-fork/)?

---

Related to: [Is it possible to hard fork a private network to Constantinople?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/72786/4575)